# Measure size in bytes in the SELECT BIGQUERY statement

Tags: java, select, google-bigquery, byte, measure

```
public TableResult executeQuery(String sqlExe) {
    TableResult tableResult = null;

    try {
        Builder builder = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(sqlExe);
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = builder.build();
        tableResult = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        return null;
    }
    return tableResult;
}
```

How to measure the data size in bytes that the select statement returns but the data has not been converted via tableResult (Size bigquery.query(queryConfig))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "setDryRun" [method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfiguration.html#setDryRun-java.lang.Boolean-), this method will return an estimate of the number of bytes read by the query; however, if you set this method to True will not run the query, but instead will return some statistics You can know more about dryRun [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries).

```
JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = newBuilder(query)
                        .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                        .setUseLegacySql(false)
                        .setDryRun(true)
                        .setDestinationTable(TableId.of("<project>", "<dataset>", "<table>"))
                        .setCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                        .setWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                        .setPriority(INTERACTIVE)
                        .build();
```